# iAd banner failed to receive banner

Tags: ios, iad

I need to show ADBanner. I am testing this on iOS 6 and here is what i am doing

```
bannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc]initWithFrame:
              CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
bannerView.delegate = self;
[bannerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self.view addSubview: bannerView];
```

It always comes in `didFailToReceiveAdWithError` with an error.

The operation couldn’t be completed. Ad inventory unavailable.

Kindly let me know where am i wrong i am using iAd first time.

Comment: Are you getting this error every time?

Comment: yes i am getting this every time.

Comment: have you enabled iAd at your iTunes Connect App settings for this app?

Comment: Have you set the ads properly? because It is normal to get this as the test iAd fill rate is not 100%. When there are no ad to serve, this delegate (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error will be called by iOS. So check that.

Comment: There is no place to enable iAd for a certain app in iTunes Connect. (like  Iducool says)

Answer (score 0):

I have been experiencing the same issue for the past 48 hours or so, as are others. It must be an issues with Apple's servers. See this post [iAd ads not appearing regardless of app used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18475936/iad-ads-not-appearing-regardless-of-app-used) 
Pretty annoying!