# iAd ads not appearing regardless of app used

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, iad

Recently I no longer receive test ads on both the simulator and devices and I can't figure out why. To test I've used Apple's iAd suite and it does not appear on there either. I've changed the fill rate to 100% and yet didFailToReceiveAdWithError is called 100% of the time so I'm starting to think it's a problem with Xcode, bearing in mind these same apps were working absolutely fine last week. I downloaded a fresh set from Apple just in case I inadvertently tweaked something.

The only change I can think of is I've set up provisioning profiles but I should think that has nothing to do with it?

Any one have any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've run Apple sample code (both on simulator and device) and ad doesn't appear too (I got the error code 3).
I've also tried to run the app with a AppID and mobile provision for an app on which I've enable iAD Network on itunesconnect, it didn't change anything.

Seems to be an Apple's server problem, the server is unable to send ads.